# tensor product of massless Poincare representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, tensor-products, unitary-representations

Consider two massless representations of the connected Poincare group $ISO_0(1,3)$ with helicities $s$ and $t$. What is the decomposition of their tensor product into irreducibles?

Massless representations with helicity s are defined in [Wigner's classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_classification) of irreducible unitary representations of the connected Poincare group, the semidirect product $ISO_0(1,3)$ of the connected Lorentz group $SO_0(1,3)$ and the 4-dimensional translation group.

Comment: What is "massless"? what is "helicity"? representation means irreducible complex finite-dimensional representation? does "$ISO_0(3,1)$" mean the same as "$SO_0(3,1)$"? (SO stands for standard orthogonal, no idea about ISO).

Comment: @YCor I means inhomogeneous, the semidirect product with the translation group. massless representations with helicity s are defined in Wigner's classification of irreducible unitary representations of the Poincare group.

Comment: @YCor Infinite-dimensional unitary representations on a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is given in the paper https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1703659 (Decomposition of Direct Products of Representations of the Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group, by J. S. Lomont).

Comment: Thanks! There is a second paper by Lomont and Moses that gives a more explicit reduction: Reduction of Reducible Representations of the Infinitesimal Generators of the Proper, Orthochronous, Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group,https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1705287

Comment: +1. Also Moussa–Stora ([1965](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=189470)), Schaaf ([1970](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=476920)), Barut–Rączka ([1977](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=495836), p. 553): $$U^{0,\,J_1}\otimes U^{0,\,J_2}\cong\int_0^\infty dM\sum_{J=|J_1-J_2|}^{\infty} \oplus U^{M,\,J}.$$

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: But this is the massive case, whereas I had asked for the massless case.

Comment: @Arnold No, massive would be $U^{M_1,\,J_1}\otimes U^{M_2,\,J_2}$.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: But massless cases have positive and negative helicity for each J, and even ignoring that, the formula you gave is not consistent with that in Lomont's paper - there is an extra contribution of massless representations with inifinite multiplicity.

Comment: It is consistent. The formula (Barut–Rączka p. 553) assumes positive helicity, includes $M=0$ in the integral, and says nothing about multiplicity. For more details see the quoted papers.